slow Mongodb regex for 200 million documents
I have a MongoDB collection with around 200 million entries for different websites. The documents are structured like this:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6647314adcfdad8dd8b1c84f"
  },
  "url": "http://example.com/login.php",
  "name": "Jack"
}

I have both a regular index and a text index on the url field.
When I try to search for subdomains for a specific domain, the query almost never completes:
{
  "url": {
    $regex: "^http://([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)*google\\.com"
  }
}

The explain feature indicates that my index is being used. I also tried simplifying the regex to search for a simple http or https pattern, but that also failed to improve performance.
The only search that is fast is an exact domain search:
{
  "url": {
    $regex: "^https://example.com"
  }
}

I'm running it on an intel i5-12450H and 32GBs of ram.
What am I doing wrong? Or is MongoDB not designed for this kind of task?

Do you expect anything else than http or https? I would simply try text search {  $text: { $search: 'google.com' }} and then a second filter with regular expression. Regular expression is in general a slow operation.

Does this answer your question? MongoDB, performance of query by regular expression on indexed fields

Solved: Just create a separate field for the domain. I extract it using python's tldextract.
It's much faster this way.
